# Matlab's nonlinear mpc results in u0 control input for all time

Tags: matlab, controls, microsoft-dynamics, mpc

I'm working with the nonlinear MPC toolbox of MATLAB and try to implement some straightforward controller. However, given an initial control signal `uk`, any control signal generated by nlmpcmove is the same as `uk` (`saveStates` is filled with whatever `uk` at zero time is).

Relevant portion of code;

```
%% Create MPC object
numStates = 12;
numOutputs = 12;
numControl = 2;

nlobj = nlmpc(numStates,numOutputs,numControl);
nlobj.Ts = constants.Ts;
Tswing = 0.1;
nlobj.PredictionHorizon = 5;
nlobj.ControlHorizon = 4;

nlobj.Model.StateFcn = @legStateFcn;
nlobj.Model.IsContinuousTime = false;

% Output function is exact state
nlobj.Model.OutputFcn = @(x,u) x;
nlobj.Jacobian.OutputFcn = @(x,u) eye(numStates);

% Weights
nlobj.Optimization.CustomCostFcn = @costFcn;
nlobj.Optimization.ReplaceStandardCost = true;

nlobj.Optimization.CustomIneqConFcn = @ineqFcn;

% Kalman filter
EKF = extendedKalmanFilter(@legStateFcn,@legMeasurementFcn);
EKF.State = x0;

%% Run MPC
u0 = zeros(numControl,1);
uk = u0;

yinit = x0;
yfinal = x0 + 1;
yref = [yinit yfinal]';

validateFcns(nlobj,yinit,u0) % THIS SAYS IT IS ALL OK

saveState = zeros(length(yinit),length(t));
saveControl = zeros(length(uk),length(t));
y = yinit;
for i = 1:length(t)
    disp(i/length(t)*100)
    
    xk = correct(EKF,y);
    saveState(:,i) = xk;
    
    uk = nlmpcmove(nlobj,xk,uk,yref(2,:));
    saveControl(:,i) = uk;

    % Predict state for next iteration
    predict(EKF,uk);
    % Implement optimal control move
    x = legStateFcn(xk,uk);
    y = x;    
end
```

Since `validateFcns(nlobj,yinit,u0)` returns all OK so I don't see a reason to show you all the function handles but just for good measure;

LegStateFcn.m;
`function xk1 = legStateFcn(xk,uk)`

costFcn.m;
`function J = costFcn(X,U,e,data)`

ineqFcn.m;
`function ineq = ineqFcn(X,U,e,data)`

legMeasurementFcn.m;
`function yk = legMeasurementFcn(xk)`

MATLAB does not whine about anything that I am doing here however, given any `u0` given before the `for-loop`, any resulting control signal from `nlmpcmove` is that same `u0`. I've debugged by renaming the `uk` before and after `nlmpcmove`, removing the `nlobj.Jacobian.OutputFcn`, simulating the resulting state (which do not adhere to the inequality constraints) and seeing that it indeed follows the dynamics of the system as I would expect.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong and I'm afraid that it is a case of such an obvious little mistake that I shouldn't have even made it in the first place.